# Calculate the average number of oscillators of an Einstein solid, in the grand canonical ensemble, when $q\gg N$

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

I am quoting from "Equilibrium and non-Equilibrium Statistical Thermodynamics", by M. Bellac.
$$Q_{(\alpha, \beta)} = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} e^{\alpha N} Z_{N}(\alpha, \beta) \hspace{1cm} (3.127)$$
Where $Q$ is the grand partition function, $Z_N$ is the canonical partition function and:
$$\beta = \frac{1}{kT} \hspace{1cm} \alpha = \frac{\mu}{kT} \hspace{1cm} (3.128)$$
$$\bar{N} =\left( \frac{\partial\ln{Q}}{\partial \alpha}\right)_\beta \hspace{1cm} (3.129)$$
In the case of an Einstein solid, $N$ is the number of oscillators and $q$ the number of quanta of energy. We are interested in the case: $$q >> N \rightarrow q \approx 10^z N, z \geq 2 \hspace{1cm} (1)$$ In this case: $$\mu = -kT\ln(\frac{q}{N}) \hspace{1cm} (2)$$ (Reference for $(2)$: Daniel V. Schroeder, An Introduction to Thermal Physics,
(Addison-Wesley, 2000) - Problems 3.35 - 3.36).$$$$
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid, we get: $$Z_{N} = \frac{N}{2 \sinh(\frac{hf}{2kT})} = N\cdot C \hspace{1cm} (3)$$
Where $$C = \frac{1}{2\sinh(\frac{hf}{2kT})} \hspace{1cm} (4)$$
$C$ depends only on $\beta$. Substituting in $(3.127)$, we get:
$$Q = C \cdot \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} e^{\alpha N} \cdot N = C \cdot \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} e^{\ln((\frac{N}{q})^N)} \cdot N = $$ $$ = C \cdot \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} N (\frac{N}{q})^N \hspace{1cm} (5)$$
Since $q >> N$, $(5)$ becomes:
$$Q \cong \left(C\cdot \frac{N}{q}\right) \Rightarrow $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ln{Q} \cong \ln{C} + \ln{\frac{N}{q}} \hspace{1cm} (6)$$
From $(3.128)$ and $(2)$: $$ \alpha = \ln{\frac{N}{q}}\hspace{1cm} (7)$$
Quoting $(3.129), (6), (7)$: $$\bar{N} = \left( \frac{\partial \ln{Q}}{\partial \alpha}\right)_{\beta} = 1 \hspace{1cm} (8)$$
I would be grateful if you could provide the correct solution and let me know of my errors in calculations, comments, etc. The main question is whether $q$ should be considered a constant, or else, if $q$ is dependent on each value $N$ takes in the sum. If I am correct in my calculations, is it equilibrium or non-equilibrium statistics?